# How to concat string with expression?

Tags: report, reportviewer

I have a textbox, and I want to set it's value to this:

> Equipment: Equipment Name

So I tried to set this at textbox expression value:

```
"Equipment: " & =Fields!EquipmentName.Value
```

Altought this doesn't work. How can I concat "Equipment" with an expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got it almost right. The expression should be:

```
= "Equipment: " & Fields!EquipmentName.Value
```